# PHP Code to Insert Text Box Text Into HTML Body

Tags: php, html

I am using the code below:

```
<form>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="link"></textarea>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="notes"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

It creates two text boxes and I was wondering how to get them from this into a different html file's body code? I think I would need PHP.

At the end I would just want it to display a message saying "Complete" and in a html file e.g code.html in the  tags it would have the contents of the two text boxes seperated by one line.

Regards!

Comment: Please write a few more details. (e.g. what do you want to see at the end)

Comment: unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: GET or POST it to same php page or another php page and retrive `$_GET` or `$_POST` and insert into other textarea

Comment: i'm amused by people answering without having a clue of the question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you would need PHP to receive the data.

See [this](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php) for a basic form that posts to a PHP page.

Comment: It needs to be in a different page.

Comment: In the <form> tag, the action variable states the destination of the data: "<form action="process.php" method="post">" will POST it to process.php.

Comment: See the example on Tizag.com linked above. You would receive the data on process.php using $var= $_POST['var']; and echo it out.

Comment: How would I make it so that if people use the form more than once it doesn't override their text it leaves a line in process.php and then pastes the new text boxes?

Comment: Right. So you want a page that people add a list of links to? Each time they submit the form, it adds it to the same page and the list keeps on growing?

Comment: Yes, exactly and if they enter notes it adds the notes below the link.

Comment: Sounds like you may need mysql for a database to store these links and notes. Prob best for a new question or a little more research. Check out these vids for a great intro into PHP and mysql: http://www.youtube.com/user/phpacademy#p/u

Answer (score 2):

you most use php html like this:

```
echo '<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">'.
'<p>PASWORD<br>'.
'<input type="text" name="name0" id="text" /><br><br>'.
'<p>BACKLINK<br>'.
'<input type="text" name="name" id="text" />'.
'<br>;'.
'<input type="submit" name="Enter" id="Enter" value="Enter" />'.
'</form>';
```

**and use if for run html**

```
   if ($_POST['name0']>''){
      your code
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

To accept input one one page and display it on another will require PHP.  The general idea:

**The HTML form page:**
Contains you HTML form where the user enters and submits their input.  The data from the form is sent to the PHP processing script.  We'll assume you use the POST method.

**The PHP processing script:**
Contains code to read the POST values and sanitize them.  This means you want to check for HTML you don't want, script tags, etc - anything you don't want.  In this case, the user will be displaying this code to themselves, so they can't really harm another user.  However, it's something important to keep in mind.  The rule of thumb - *never trust user input* - always check it and clean it.  Now that the PHP script has read and cleaned the data, you want to display it.

**The PHP display script:**
Contains the HTML of the page and PHP code to display the values you captured in the PHP processing script.

**Other notes:**
The PHP processing and display scripts can live in the same file.  You will have to process before you display.  Alternately, you can run the processing script and then include the display script.  Both will work.